# find optimized height

Tags: calculus

Please help me with this word problem:

> A light is to be placed directly above the center of a circular plot of $r=30\text{ ft}$, at such a height that the edge of the plot will get maximum illumination. Find the height if the intensity $I$ at any point on the edge is directly proportional to the cosine of the angle of incidence and inversely proportional to the square of the distance from the source.

So far I think I set up the equation like so:

$$I = \frac{\cos\theta}{h^2}$$

Where $h$ is the distance from the source. I assume we must use some inverse trig identities and then take derivative wrt to $h$, and set to zero to find the critical numbers. But my expression has $3$ variables which I don't know how to take the derivative? It seems I'm missing a conceptual step. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let $h$ be the height, $d$ the distance and $r$ the radius. The cosine of the angle of incidence is equal to $h/d$. Thus, intensity is proportional to $h/d^3$. Since $d=\sqrt{h^2+r^2}$, we get that intensity is proportional to $$\frac{h}{\sqrt{(h^2+r^2)^3}}$$

The derivative of this function is $$\frac{r^2-2h^2}{\sqrt{(r^2+h^2)^5}}$$ which is equal to zero when $h=\sqrt{r^2/2}$. Thus, for $r=30$, we get $h=\sqrt{900/2}=30/\sqrt{2}\approx21.2\, ft$.

The corresponding angle of incidence is $\arctan(\sqrt{2})\approx0.955$ radians, corresponding to $\approx54.7$ degrees.

Note that you could obtain the same results by calling $\alpha$ the angle of incidence and by observing that the distance is equal to $r/\sin(\alpha)$. Thus, intensity is proportional to $\cos(\alpha)\sin^2(\alpha)/r^2$. The derivative is $$\frac{2\sin(\alpha)-3\sin^3(\alpha)}{r^2}$$
which equals zero for $2-3\sin^2(\alpha)=0$, and then $\sin(\alpha)=\sqrt{2/3}$. Because this also implies $\cos(\alpha)=\sqrt{1-2/3}=\sqrt{1/3}$, we finally get $\tan(\alpha)=\sqrt{2}$, and then $\alpha=\arctan(\sqrt{2})$.

Comment: thanks so much ! it is clear now. however, can you please explain for the second method if the value for h would be the same as the first method? given sin(alpha) = sqrt(2/3), that would give h = 1 ? since i used h^2 = d^2 - r^2. it seems to me that the values for h are not the same? thanks again!

Comment: The result is the same. The first method gives $h=30/\sqrt{2}\approx21.2$. Using the second method, you have $d=r/\sin\alpha=30/\sqrt{2/3}$ and $h=d\cos(\alpha)=30\sqrt{1-2/3}/\sqrt{2/3}=30\sqrt{(1-2/3)/(2/3)}=30\sqrt{(1/3)/(2/3)}=30\sqrt{1/2}=30/\sqrt{2}\approx21.2$.

Comment: The first method is probably "simpler ", as does not require trigonometric functions

Comment: If you found my answer useful, consider the possibility of upvoting. Thanks!